# How to Generate Unique Serial Numbers for Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Our application has several entities and was developed with `MySQL` database. All our entities `extends` a common base entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntityData implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * Data identifier (Usually holds Primary Key)
     */
    private Long id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the id to set
     */
    public void setId(final Long value)
    {
        this.id = value;
    }
}
```

All our entities extends `BaseEntityData` and everything worked perfectly on `MySQL` database. We didn't border to test on `Oracle database` during development. We now want to test on `Oracle database` cos of different client requirements but discovered that `Oracle database` does not generate serial numbers for primary key and sometimes generate duplicate keys. How can modify this super class `BaseEntityData` in order to generate unique keys for all our tables. There are over 300 entities extending this super class.

Comment: Use a sequence, that's the way Oracle does it (and most other DBMS). I don't really know JPA, but I think there is a generater strategy for "sequences"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name less horse is right. For oracle you need to create a sequence and use that to generate the ID.

The annotations will look like this

```
@id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ENTITY_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="ENTITY_SEQUENCE", sequenceName="ENTITY_SEQUENCE")
```

It looks like you are going to define the id in a super class intended to be extended. If that is the case strongly consider moving the IDs to a sub class level. In a large enterprise application with many objects you may want to use separate ID sequences for separate entities.

Comment: This is exactly what i don't want to do. The entities are really many. Having the `ids` duplicated in all the entities is what we don't really want to undertake now. Is there no way of having the `ids` in the super class and still generate different id for the entities.

Comment: If you want to make sure that the id is unique amongst all the entities then keep in in the super class. But keep in mind that there is an upper limit to a oracle sequence..... Anyway whats wrong with having unrelated entities having he same ID?

Comment: What i want to achieve is to have unique `ids` for the different tables. But the must be unique for the tables. e.g. `table_1` will have `ids` say `1, 2, 3, ...`, `table_2` have `ids` `1, 2, 3, ...`. This means that all tables will generate serial numbers. Is it possible to achieve this with having `id` defined in the base class and using oracle database and sequence generator.

Comment: OK first tel me is this a base class that all entities will extend from or a base class in an actual hierarchy? With the application being made up from multiple inheritance hierarchies?

Comment: Yes. It is a base class that all entities are already extending. If you take a good look at the question, you will see that the application is already working. So all entities in the system are already using the Base class as a source for their id.

Comment: Yes I missed the part where it's a mapped super class. Well in that case go with a single sequence then. But make sure you are willing to accept it's max value... For the table per ID option you will need to add the mapping information to the subclass itself with a different sequence for each table.\

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31519/discussion-between-uchenna-nwanyanwu-and-thihara)